# How to find the close range in object of array, and pick close range and extract the object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to find the closest object in DataSet Array with a starting point and end point.

```
    startTime = 1559923201;
    endTime  = 1560009601; 
    DataSet  = [
    {"time":1549923201,"value":12}, 
    {"time":1559923200,"value":10},        
    {"time":1559923000,"value":5},        
    {"time":1560058490,"value":4},        
    {"time":1560058800,"value":3},  
    {"time":1560059500,"value":2}];
```

I could find closest, how can I find the index of the array.

```
var start = DataSet.reduce(function(prev,curr) {
return (Math.abs(curr["time"] - startTime) < Math.abs(prev["time"] - startTime) ? curr : prev);
}); 

var end = DataSet.reduce(function(prev,curr) {
return (Math.abs(curr["time"] - endTime) < Math.abs(prev["time"] - endTime) ? curr : prev);
});
```

And the result I am looking for is, very close range from DataSet such as following:

```
    ResultSet  = [
    {"time":1559923200,"value":10},        
    {"time":1559923000,"value":5}];
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the data set and adjust for the range of acceptable times by some `r`:

```
const r = 500 // half a second either side of start time
DataSet.filter(d => (d.time >= startTime-r) && (d.time <= endTime+r))
```

returns:

```
[
    {"time":1559923200,"value":10},        
    {"time":1559923000,"value":5}
]
```